# IDE Controller Error causing BSOD?

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, sp3, ide-controller

So I was thinking before that a series of "SideBySide" errors were causing BSODs on my netbook (Samsung N120 + 2GB RAM). But I think it is an "atapi" error which says:

"The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Ide\IdePort0."

Has anyone else had this error and is there a fix for it? Also, I had other "atapi" errors before it saying:

"The device, \Device\Ide\IdePort0, did not respond within the timeout period."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various things could cause these errors:

- Multiple CD/DVD drives on the same IDE channel that aren't configured properly
- There are problems with the IDE0 port on your motherboard
- There are problems with your hard drive or CD/DVD drive
- Problems with the IDE cable itself
- Software error

...among some other things.

You may be interested in the articles on EventID.net, specifically [Event ID 9](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=9&eventno=2060&source=atapi&phase=1) and [Event ID 11](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=11&eventno=3421&source=atapi&phase=1).

Comment: Well, turns out I had a bad hard drive, so I'm replacing that. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: You're most welcome!